# How to loop through json array using jquery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was trying to show my json data using jquery.each().
now this is the json

```
 var json = 
  [
    {"id":"1","tagName":"apple"},
    {"id":"2","tagName":"orange"
  }]
```

then i can show it

```
 $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.tagName);
 });
```

But my json is

```
 {
  "Message": "Success",
  "Code": "200",
  "Payload": [
    {
     "year": "2015",
     "month": "6",
     "fileCount": "985",
     "totalFileSize": "2820"
    },
    {
     "year": "2015",
     "month": "7",
     "fileCount": "15347",
     "totalFileSize": "66549"
    }
   ]
  }
```

Now I need to read the data inside the Payload. please help me with

Comment: What have you tried? Wouldn’t simply `$.each(json.Payload, function(`…`) {`…`});` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply. `Payload` is property of the object that you have provided, which can be accessed like this: `json.Payload`. So you should pass it as the first argument to `$.each()` method. Here you go:

```
$.each(json.Payload, function(idx, obj) {
     console.log(obj);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wxwkxbd/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$.map(array,function(obj,index){
     console.log(obj)
});
```

for iterating through an array